# Can access arguments only be specified once for all sub-routes?

Tags: 7, routes

For example:

I would start off by setting this.

```
$items['admin'] = array(
 'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

But the anytime after I use admin in my menu hook it would take on the same access arguments. So below would take on the same access argument as the above.

```
$items['admin/users'] = array(
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
 'page arguments' => array('get_users_page'),
 'title' => 'Users Listing',
 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

EDIT: To put in better words, thanks Jaypan. Can access arguments be inherited from their parent's access arguments?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but if you are asking if access arguments can be inherited from their parent's access arguments, the answer is no. You need to explicitly set them for each path.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the documentation for [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) access arguments are inherited from the parent route only if the access callback is inherited, and that only happens for [`MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK/7.x) routes.

For the code shown in the question, this would happen only if it would be written as follows.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['admin'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('get_users_page'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  $items['admin/users'] = array(
    'title' => 'Users Listing',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

I take the route names are used just as example. Since admin is already defined from [`system_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_menu/7.x), it is better not to use route names containing admin or admin/.

As side note, the page callback is inherited from the parent route, in any case.

Comment: Yeah, just needed some clarification. I figured admin would probably be the best example for the subject matter. Thanks for the response!!